# Why could an android application crash after opening too many applications in the same device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am building an android bluetooth application that justs waits for bluetooth connections with some devices. The problem is that the application crashes after opening too many (10+) applications in the same device without closing them. The application works fine if I dont use the device(opening other apps).

I thought that a particular app might cause the problem, but I've checked this.

Why could this happen? Is it a memory issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a service? Is your app supposed to run "all the time"?
You should probably read about activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). Android is very strict about memory management. What happens is when there's a memory lack, Android can shutdown any activity without warning.